# How to force Fill of a DataRow?

Tags: c#, ado.net

In C# I have a DataSet. I call Fill to load the rows from the data source (an Oracle database). When I modify some rows and call Update then I sometimes get concurrency violations in case the data has changed in the database after my Fill. These exceptions are caught by a "RowUpdated" event handler that I attached to my OracleDataAdapter.

I want to systematically overwrite the data in the data source with my data. In other words, I want to implement a "last saved wins". How can I implement that? I believe that for my modified row that I am trying to save and that is now in error (ie. Status = ErrorsOccured), I must find a way to refresh the Original version of the row with the data from the database whilst preserving the values of the Current version. Indeed will a call to Update only succeed if there is a match between the Original version of my row and what is in the database .. Strangely, I found not function to achieve just that .. Thanks

Comment: You will have to write an additional update query that doesn't depend on the original row values to decide whether or not to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

From reading the "Best Practices for Using ADO.NET" (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971481.aspx) I discovered that I can use the DataTable Merge for that :

*If you want to refresh a table with the current values from the serve while retaining any changes made to the rows in the table, you must first populate it with DataAdapter.Fill, fill a new DataTable, and then Merge that DataTable into the DataSet with a preserveChanges value of true.*